Which directive to change in OpenVPN server config?
Setup: OpenVPN Server running on my Synology DS118 NAS. Default server config and key files. Nothing changed in the server-side config files.
Clients all running on Windows 11 Pro. This is a workgroup, no LDAP, no AD.
Nothing changed in the default client-side config files other than the directive "explicit-exit-notify 1" added. This makes the client immediately send a "session terminated" (or sth like that) message to the server, and as a result the server terminates the VPN session.
Problem: This works perfectly other than in scenarios when the user forgets to manually disconnect the VPN session through the GUI client. So eg. the user  reboots the PC, then tries to log into the VPN again and then it fails because to the server, that past terminated VPN session is still active, but in fact it's not.
Workaround I've tried I have written a batch script that terminates all VPN sessions immediately on the client-side. Here below:
@echo off 
set openVpnGuiPath="C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin\openvpn-gui.exe" 
set "disconnectCommand=--command disconnect_all" 
start "" %openVpnGuiPath% %disconnectCommand% 

I've tried both the Computer Shutdown Script GPO, and the Task Scheduler "Source: System, User32, Event ID 1074". Neither managed to get it to run and do what it is to do. If I go into Task Scheduler and check the script after reboot, it says "Task hasn't yet run".
Server-side directives I can see that might be relevant here:

keepalive 10 60

If I understand correctly, on the server side, this means that the server will ping the client every 10 seconds, and within 120 seconds, if at least 1 ping hasn't been answered, the session will be rebooted.
On the Client side, however, the client will ping the server 1x every 10 seconds, and if no ping is answered in 60 seconds, the client will consider the VPN session terminated.

status /tmp/ovpn_status_2_result 30

If I understand correctly, this means that status file will be updated every 30 seconds but I am uncertain as to whether this does anything far as the server seeing the VPN sessions' actual current status or not...

status-version 2

If I understand correctly, this only regards the level of verbosity and the format of the status file above.
Question: In order to fix this issue, do I need to change the keepalive directive? Is THAT what's responsible to how fast the server detects dead and alive VPN sessions and terminates them accordingly? Or is it the status file?
Should I attempt "keepalive 5 5" on the server-side?
